# How to append data to Zend_Auth object

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

Good Day to All,

I have the following code which appends stores data to `Zend_Auth` object

```
    $auth        = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    $dbAdapter   = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
    $dbAdapter,
                'account', 
                'email', 
                'password',
                'delete_flag=0'
    );
    //MD5(?) AND  .. add this along with the prev where condn of delete flag...

    $authAdapter->setIdentity($loginDataArray['email'])
    ->setCredential($loginDataArray['password']);

    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter); 
    var_dump($result);

    if ($result->isValid()) {

        $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();

        // the details you wan to store in the session
        $userDetails = array();         

        $userDetails['account_id']    = $account_id;
        $userDetails['email']      = $loginDataArray['email'];

        $authStorage->write($userDetails);
}
```

Now, How do i append any more data in the later part of the session. How do i edit the same Zend_Auth object later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication state is stored in the registered Auth Storage. By default this is Zend_Session. You can get session by this

```
$namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
```

then do somthing like this

```
$namespace->newname = "newvalue";
```

Comment: Thanks Chandresh . :) .. mujhe tho aapke desk pe aake pooch lena chahiye tha ..  :)

Comment: Cheers @Archer. Next time aap phone o friend kar sakte hai. Anyway stakeoverflow hume aisa hi ehsaas karata hai ki hum aas paas me hai :)

Comment: well .. i literally ment it .. mujhe aapke desk pe aana chahiye tha.. :D

Answer (score 1):

ok, you don't 'edit' Zend_Auth Identity. You either have an identity or not. You can set, read, write or clear storage through the Zend_Auth object.

However many of us use this same data for various display purposes so a solution that often works is to set the data to a different session namespace or a registry key when the identity is being stored or just update the session that Zend_Auth creates as *chandresh*_ *cool* suggests.

```
if ($result->isValid()) {

        $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();

        // the details you wan to store in the session
        $userDetails = array();         

        $userDetails['account_id']    = $account_id;
        $userDetails['email']      = $loginDataArray['email'];
        //add user data to registry
        $user = Zend_Registry::set('user', $userDetails);

        $authStorage->write($userDetails);
}
```

if you really want to do your own thing you can write your own storage adapter by implementing `Zend_Auth_Storage_Interface` or you can write your own Auth adapter by implementing `Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface` and include the storage component in the adapter.

Lots of choices, good luck.